# Compression Strings & List: Type Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, compression, zlib

I keep running into a lot of type errors, after trying quite a few ways. Here is the code I have right now, that I need to be able to compress into a file.

```
import zlib
sentence = input("Enter the text you want to compress: ")
listSentence = sentence.split(" ")
d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = (i+1)
    values += [d[word]]
coms = zlib.compress(sentence.encode('utf-8'))
comv = zlib.compress(values.encode('utf-8'))
with open("listofwords.txt", "wb") as myfile:
    myfile.write(coms)
    myfile.write(comv)
```

I keep getting a type error:
`Type error: List does not support the buffer interface`

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: You always need to post the traceback when you want help with an error.

Comment: Well, like the actual error says, `values` is a list, and you can't encode a list. What are you trying to achieve? Note that in your code `values` is just the list of integers from 1 to the number of unique words in your sentence.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Both the values and the input need to be compressed.

Comment: But what does that mean? Print out `values` before the error, it will be something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. What do you want to output?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The overall aim of the program is to take an input from the user, assign values to each word. And then it needs to be able to compress the input and values down to the file. No output is required.

Comment: What are the values meant to represent? You can convert them to a string `' '.join(str(v) for v in values)` but not sure that helps.

Comment: You're writing them to the file though; that is output\. **How** do you want them to be written to the file? In what format?]

Comment: @AChampion The values are the position of the words in the sentence, example Ask is positon 1.

Comment: @DanielRoseman in a .txt format

Comment: Sigh, I give up. I can't get you to tell me what the file should look like.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't know what you mean. The file should be .txt, and compressed. There is no more to it.

Comment: Just to be clear you are not compressing the file, you are compressing individual lines and writing them out independently to the file. You will not be able to use an external tool to uncompress. The list of values don't include which word the number relates to, so it's unnecessary - you can recreate this list when you uncompress the sentence.

Comment: @AChampion Sorry about that- I just realized how unclear I have been. I'm not compress the actual file, just the user's input & values into the file. Sorry once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want

```
import zlib
sentence = input("Enter the text you want to compress: ")
listSentence = sentence.split()
d = dict()
values = [d.setdefault(w,sentence.find(w)) for w in listSentence]
print(values)
coms = zlib.compress(sentence.encode('utf-8'))
comv = zlib.compress(bytes(values))
with open("listofwords.txt", "wb") as myfile:
    myfile.write(coms)
    myfile.write(comv)
```

which produces, for example

```
Enter the text you want to compress: hello world hello
[0, 6, 0]
```

and a file with the compressed sentence followed by the compressed list of the position of the first occurrence of each word in the sentence, i.e.

```
mbb@dev:~/SO/py$ cat listofwords.txt 
x��H���W(�/�IQ��; �x�c`c
```

Note: the dictionary named `d` is there to cache the position of the words as they are found in the sentence, in order to avoid scanning the sentence for words that have been encountered already.

Note2: I'd personally give the output file another suffix, e.g. `.bin`

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a count but the position of the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for that, works great! Sorry for being unclear on this!

Comment: You are welcome. if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.